# What pumps blood through a listener's body?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

On Roshar much of the native animal life, including the [listeners](https://stormlightarchive.fandom.com/wiki/Listeners), have [gemhearts](https://stormlightarchive.fandom.com/wiki/Gemheart) where a normal organic heart would be.  Besides that, and their orange blood, the general make up of a listener's body seems to be more or less vaguely human like.

Sanderson's world building tends to be pretty extensive if not pedantic.  Some of the [Cosmere](https://stormlightarchive.fandom.com/wiki/Cosmere?so=search) works cross the line into [sci-fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_fantasy).  So it makes we wonder if he has ever answered a question about this or if there is some hint in the lengthy texts that make up the stories.

Has Sanderson ever mentioned how the gemheart creatures pump blood?
Is it some kind of vague magic?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[They also have normal "meat hearts".](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/482/#e15302) The gemheart serves a distinct Investiture-related purpose ("resonating with the tunes of Roshar, that sort of stuff"), it's not just stuck there in the place of a normal fleshy blood-pumper.

This is alluded to in the Eila Stele, which implies that singers possess multiple things that they call a "heart", contrary to humans having just one:

> *These [humans] know no songs. They cannot hear Roshar, and where they go, they bring silence. They look soft, with no shell, but they are hard. **They have but one heart,** and it cannot ever live.*

Comment: How does that quote imply what you say it does? "They have but one heart" means they have only one heart, not more than one.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Rather major spoilers there, but that quote is referring to humans from the perspective of the Listeners. Since one heart is odd to the speaker, that implies they have more than one.

Comment: @TheDarkCanuck Aha, got it. Sorry.